# How to avoid RFC1918 A record, leaking on the external network?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, bind

How to avoid RFC1918 A record, leaking on the external network ?

I can use the view to achieve my request ,but when the dns record more and more in the management will become very troublesome.

I wonder if there is a simpler approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is you setup today?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of the following ways to solve the problem of private IPs leakage:

1. Use DNS views to split the zones into two zones: one for private records allowed for local clients only and the other one for public records. If you don't like this option, you can look next.
2. Use a dedicated DNS server for private records used and accessible only by local clients, and use another different DNS server for public records used by other clients. This can be enforced by a firewall.
3. Use only one single view without using any private addresses. Turn all your servers IPs to public in DNS zone. Local clients will use public IPs in this case. This requires two things: no need to hide any name from your DNS, and doing the right routing/NATing configuration within your network.

I can not recommend any single solution. This depends on your setup and the available options you have.

Comment: Could an external query respond to "Record exists, but can not query content"?